# Adding custom data to wordpress customer order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, customization, orders

I need to capture a variable for tracking referers from an incoming URL and append it to an order in wordpress/woocommerce.   Currently in the themes header.php file I have:

```
    if(!empty($_GET['refID'])) $_SESSION['refID'] = $_GET['refID'];
```

Then, in my themes functions.php file I have:

```
    if(!empty($_SESSION['refID'])) $rID = $_SESSION['refID'];
    else $rID = "no var set";

    add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_add_order_meta', 10, 2 );
    function my_add_order_meta( $order_id, $rID ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'refID', $rID );
    }
```

The session variable appears in the WP session,  but nothing appears in the order after its posted.  I have very little experience working with WP/woocommerce and would like to know if this is even the proper method for doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some unknown reason,  the variable wasn't being passed from the session to $rID.  By using the actual session variable the function is now posting the additional data to the order.  I have also substituted $rID for $posted in the function call:

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_add_order_meta', 10, 2 ); 
    function my_add_order_meta( $order_id, $posted ) {
    update_post_meta($order_id, 'refID', $_SESSION['refID']);   
    }
```

Comment: Isn't this essentially what I answered?

Comment: Yes,  just written up differently and in an easier to follow format for me.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the session variable, but aren't using it...I believe your function should look more like the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_add_order_meta' );
function my_add_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    // Get the stored refID
    $refID = isset( $_SESSION['refID'] ) ? $_SESSION['refID'] : null;
    // Update the refID meta
    update_post_meta( $order_id, 'refID', $refID );
}
```

Comment: My mistake,  I forgot to include my if/else argument.  Edited the post to reflect that.

Comment: @Tidan, that still doesn't matter. Even if you include those lines, you're never passing `$rID` to the function...You're only defining it as a parameter. Give my code a shot...it should work fine.

Comment: Following your lead I came up with something that appears to be working.  Question:  is update_post_meta the correct method to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: From what I can tell, yes, that is the correct function to be using.